# Vimeo player API $f(iframe) value is null in https page

Tags: jquery, vimeo

I am using Vimeo player in my web site for a video.

I am using the following code that was given in the vimeo web site.

http://jsfiddle.net/bdougherty/HfwWY/light/

The above jsfiddle link is from the vimeo player javascript api link : https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

I am using the exact same code except my video link in the iframe tag is different.

```
 <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/MY VIDEO CODE?api=1&amp;player_id=player1" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Before the video loads I am displaying a loading icon.

I am using the ready and play event to hide the loading icon. The following is my code.

```
    var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
    player = $f(iframe);

    var videoSource = $('iframe#player1').prop('src');
    $('iframe#player1').prop('src',videoSource + "&autoplay=1");

    if(player !== null && player !== undefined){
        $("#loadingIcon").show();

        // When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
        player.addEvent('ready', function() {

            $("#loadingIcon").hide();

            player.addEvent('play', onPlay);
            //player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
            //player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
            // player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
        });
    }


    // function onPause(id) {}

    // function onFinish(id) {}

    function onPlay(id) {
        if($("#loadingIcon").length > 0)
            $("#loadingIcon").hide();
    }
```

The problem I am having is the loading icon getting displayed and not hiding away after the video is ready or starts playing.

Previously, in my https page, the object "player's" value was coming as null. So I added the if condition. It fixed the issue. But, now even that seems to be not working. So, when the video is playing the loading icon is still present.

In addition to this, firebug is throwing errors saying:

Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'.
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'.
Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'.

(I have pasted it 3 times, because firebug displays it 3 times)

But the video is still playing fine.

If anyone has encountered this issue before, please help.

Comment: You aren't supposed to just fiddle around with src's of iframes like that. Before injecting it on to your page, make sure it's pointed to the correct src.

Comment: I wanted the video to play when a button is clicked, so I added that autoplay=1 to the src. And yes src is pointed to the correct source. The video plays without any problem, the problem I am having is the loading icon which does not hide after the video is ready or starts playing.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle illustrating your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need FroogaLoop.js Library

Comment: Could you please add more context to your answer?  Why do you believe this is the answer to a 5 year old question and how would  FroogaLoop.js Library be used to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

FroogaLoop.js was being blocked, when I included it in my site, I no longer got this error.